# Error: No se puede volver a de clarar la varible com ámbito de bloque 'name' en typesript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-7

estoy aprendiendo typescript, y quisiera que me expliquen porfa porque me suelta un error cuando intento crear la varible name, como se ve en la imagen no lo volví a crear en otra parte. Gracias agradeceria su aporte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui lo que me pinta en consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es posible que tengas otro archivo donde se esté declarando una constante `name`? Al estar en la misma carpeta es posible que alguna configuración del IDE haga que el compilador considere el otro archivo como parte de la ejecución

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta y eso es lo que me sale en consola, pero lo mas curioso es que solo tengo ese archivo y mas nada.

Comment: @JheffersonAlbornozVara `name` es una variable global  que [está declarada en windows](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30682#issuecomment-478463124). Por favor, usa otro nombre que no interfiera con los tipos declarados en el dom. Por ejemplo `_name`

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias. Voy a buscar más de esas varibles globales de windows

Comment: Debes poner tu código y el correspondiente error como texto. Aunque ya te hayan respondido, si alguien quisiera reproducir tu problema tendría que transcribir mirando los screenshots. No crees que es impráctico?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez No es de "Windows" (el sistema operativo), es del objeto "window" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Comment: @PabloLozano yo nunca dije que fuera el sistema operativo, simplemente se me fue una s.

Comment: El post al que enlazas tiene también esa errata y el OP la ha asumido, simplemente quería evitar confusiones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque let permite declarar variables limitando su alcance al bloque, declaración, o expresión donde se está usando en tu caso en el lugar que la declaras alcanza el ambito de la biblioteca
La estas declarando en un ámbito global pertenecerá al ámbito global
donde name  se declaro  por lo que la definición de tipo global choca con su declaración .  Si busco la definición del error en VSC  muestra  en lib.dom.d.ts en la linea 17330 `declare const name: void;`o sea es ya usada por la biblioteca si la declaras dentro de un modulo con export {} ya no te mostrara el error tampoco si le das su propio ámbito ejemplo

```js
let name='hola';// te advierte del choque
name='justo'
console.log(name)
if (name='justo') {
  let name= 'Austria';
  // esta dentro de un  ambito no choca
  //  accedida dentro su bloque 
  console.log(name); 
}
//export {}; si en typescript lo marcaramos como modulo
```

Tenes un buen tutorial introductorio de modulos [modulos](https://www.manejandodatos.es/2015/10/modulos-internos-en-typescript/#:%7E:text=Los%20m%C3%B3dulos%20en%20TypeScript&text=Consiste%20en%20agrupar%20todo%20dentro,de%20incluir%20la%20palabra%20export.)
Los módulos permiten agrupar código con igual finalidad dentro de un modulo la declaración de name ya no te daría advertencia
tutorial [mas sobre modulos](https://apuntes.de/typescript/modules-in-typescript/#gsc.tab=0)
Tambien si te inicias con typescript seria de utilidad que vieras antes Javascript--->[let js](https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript)

Comment: Gracias, si eso también estoy aprendiendo, hacer export y crearlas ahí

Comment: fíjate que al confeccionar la pregunta en la parte superior en la barra selecciona fragmento JavaScript es sencillo esta al lado de imagen así tus preguntas las haces con código desde el editor saludos